# python grouping dicts by many keys

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
    my_list = [{
        "name": "alin",
        "id": 2,
        "note": -10
    },{
        "name": "alin",
        "id": 2,
        "note": -10
    },{
        "name": "alin",
        "id": 2,
        "note": -10
    },{
        "name": "milanie",
        "id": 3,
        "note": 11
    },{
        "name": "martin",
        "id": 3,
        "note": 11}]
```

and I want to group them by occurrence, I have already did this :

```
my_list = [{
        "name": "alin",
        "id": 2,
        "note": -10,
        "occ": 3
    },
    },{
        "name": "milanie",
        "id": 3,
        "note": 11
    },{
        "name": "martin",
        "id": 3,
        "note": 11}]
```

my question is his how to group by id and note and get one dict like this :

```
{ "name": "martin",
  "id": 3,
  "note": 11,
  "occ":2}
```

Comment: What is the entry: `"oc":2`?

Comment: You want to group the initial list of dict based on similar id and note?

Comment: oc is the number of occurrences

Comment: i didn't think to do it like that, i mean starting by grouping by id and note and then name

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. You have only used `occ` in the first dict and in the last dict you have used `oc`. So does it mean you want to group after finding the oc?

Comment: sorry i didn't pay attention oc is occ sorry

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in pandas pretty easily.

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = [{
    "name": "alin",
    "id": 2,
    "note": -10
},{
    "name": "alin",
    "id": 2,
    "note": -10
},{
    "name": "alin",
    "id": 2,
    "note": -10
},{
    "name": "milanie",
    "id": 3,
    "note": 11
},{
    "name": "martin",
    "id": 3,
    "note": 11}]

pd.DataFrame(my_list).groupby(['name','id','note']).size().reset_index(name='occ').to_dict('records')
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'alin', 'id': 2, 'note': -10, 'occ': 3},
 {'name': 'martin', 'id': 3, 'note': 11, 'occ': 1},
 {'name': 'milanie', 'id': 3, 'note': 11, 'occ': 1}]
```

Edit:

Based on your requirements, you can use named agg to explicitly define your columns and aggregations.  In this case we will take the `last` name per group to get `martin`, but you could use `first` to get `melanie` if you wanted.  If you desire a specific name you may want to sort values by name first in order to guarantee what name you get.

```
pd.DataFrame(my_list).groupby(['id','note']).agg(name=('name','last'),occ=('id','count')).reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Output

```
[{'id': 2, 'note': -10, 'name': 'alin', 'occ': 3},
 {'id': 3, 'note': 11, 'name': 'martin', 'occ': 2}]
```

Comment: i did that, but this is not my question: 
this is the wanted output, i feel blocked 
`[{'name': 'alin', 'id': 2, 'note': -10, 'occ': 3},
 {'name': 'martin', 'id': 3, 'note': 11, 'occ': 2}]`

Comment: @salahmazroai Why does the second name have to be `'martin'` and not `'milanie'`?

Comment: if they have the same id and note so the result must be one `martin` or `milanie` and `occ` is the sum of the `occ`

Comment: Why `martin` and not `melanie`?  Are you arbitrarily choosing one?

Comment: yes arbitrarily it should be one of them